Анимирование групп объектов Roblox Studio TweenService
Хотел спросить, как в Roblox Studio двигать группы объектов с помощью TweenService? Просто у меня есть детализированная модель стола, и я просто хочу её подвинуть, но мне надо создавать для каждого парта переменную и отдельно в скрипте для каждого парта прописывать отдельные 3 строки, а этих партов там больше 200. Также пробовал анимировать именно родителя (Parent) у этого стола, но двигается только этот парт. Дочерние парты не двигаются :(
Я надеюсь есть люди, которые знают что-то про TweenService и Roblox Studio и смогут мне помочь! Заранее спасибо каждому, кто отвечает и пытается помочь!

можно попробовать сделать невидимый парт, убрать у него колизию, после отправить в модель, а все остальные модельки поместить внутрь этого парта, и уже ему прописывать движение
